# Python create table from log file

Tags: python, logging

The input is a log file that basically contains reaction times and other data from participants in an experiment. What I want as output is a table where each piece of information is in one field of its own so that I can then calculate means over columns etc.
I'm having some difficulties here and there and hoped that someone could help since I'm new to Python. What I have so far is:

```
# loading file and reading it character by character:
with open("......log") as characters:

    while True:
        character = characters.read(1)
        if not character:
            break
        print(character)

# the idea here is: if the character is a tab, go to the next column. If it is the end of a line, go to a new row. Otherwise print the character. This should fill each table field with one string/number.

for character in range(???):   #what do I enter in "range"? I want the for loop   
                             to run over all characters in the file 
    if character == '\t':
        #go to next column. My idea: create an empty table first, with 
         variables c = number of columns and r = number of rows, 
         so at this point I can enter "c = c + 1"
    elif character == '\n':
        #go to next row -> r = r + 1
    else
        print(character)
```

So to sum up, my questions are:
1) What do I enter in `range`? 
2) How do I implement adding columns and rows? Can I just literally type `c = c+1` and it will work if I defined c before?

3) ...How do I define `c` before, i.e. how do I go about initializing an empty table? Or is there another elegant way?

Thank you in advance and apologies if I cannot verbalize certain things in a way that makes perfect sense, I'm still new to this and only have experience in Matlab which is quite different

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you maybe provide a short example of the log? Shouldnt be too hard to help you out then :) PS: maybe try to use pandas datframe for reading the log file. It might give you your desired output

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python read write file tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial site; your questions here are better answered by existing resources.

Comment: @Aaron: The log file looks like this (after some first lines with general information), I entered /// to indicate new lines:

Durchgang1 1 Pulse 1 641466 631301 1    ///
Durchgang1 1 Pulse 1 660866 650701 1   ///
Durchgang1 1 Pulse 1 680266 670101 1   ///

Comment: I agree with @Prune, this is off topic IMO. See: [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You should think to log file as an usual delimited file.
I suggest you to use *pandas* with **read_csv** specifiyng which delimiter you want to define the data in log  file.

For example the following text is my log:

```
2019-12-11 22:56:19,467 - INFO - test
2019-12-11 22:58:10,228 - INFO - test
2019-12-11 22:58:23,968 - INFO - test
2019-12-11 22:58:34,459 - INFO - test
```

If you want to define a column for every value between dash (**-**) you can use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("test.log", delimiter = "-", header = None)
print(data)
print(data.head())
```

Comment: This makes sense! But I'm getting the message "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 13"...

Comment: @TatjanaSchmidt For your log files it should be `'\t'` as `delimiter`, if I understand the according comment in your code right... And you'll need to skip some number of rows iiuc, or are your header rows starting all with a comment signaling character like `#`? You can choose that or define sth like that, too... Simply check the kwargs of [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @TatjanaSchmidt that error can happen when is not set the right delimiter.
Can you post some example line of your log ?
So we can better understand and help you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working with the assumption that your log looks like the following

```
24    378    58
6     49     1
```

And you wish to get the means of the columns, as in

```
15    213.5    29.5
```

Then the following implementation could suffice:

```
import functools
import re


def sum(columnTotals, line):
    cells = re.split(r'\t+', line)

    for cell in enumerate(cells):
        columnTotals[cell[0]] = columnTotals.get(cell[0], 0) + float(cell[1])

    return columnTotals


def main():

    with open('/path/to/log') as log:
        rows = [line.strip() for line in log if line.strip() != '']
        columnTotals = functools.reduce(sum, enumerate(rows), {})
        numberOfRows = len(rows)

    means = [columnTotal/numberOfRows for columnTotal in columnTotals.values()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Disclaimers:

- Log size has not been put in to consideration, and this solution is NOT space efficient
- It's assumed that the input is correctly formatted according to specification (e.g. cells are separated by tabs and cell are numbers only)
- I've not tested the script, but I'm confident it should lead you to the idea you're looking